# Java RuntimeException cannot Serialize UUID

Tags: java, android, runtime

**AndroidSide:**

```
public static int DeviceMonitor(UUID Employeeid)
    {


        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(SOAPNAMESPACE,SOAPLOGINMETHOD);
        request.addProperty("Employeeid",Employeeid);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        Log.d("Device insert out",""+ envelope.bodyOut.toString());
        try{HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAPURL);
            httpTransport.call(SOAPLOGINACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject response=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

            id=Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(0).toString());

        }catch (Exception exception){
            Log.d("Device Insertion Service Exception:::","\tExceptionMessage:"+exception.toString());
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }   
        return id;}
```

**WCF Side:**

```
public int InsertEmployee(Guid Empid)
{
    int counter = 0;

    WrosDBEntities dbContext = new WrosDBEntities();

        EmployeeType emp = new EmployeeType();
        emp .SecurityID = Guid.NewGuid();
        emp .FK_EMPID = Empid;
        context.AddToDeviceSecurities(emp );
       context.SaveChanges();
counter++;        
return counter;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i have this error Java RuntimeException cannot Serialize UUID of employee id when call service of wcf please i need the help for this...what to do ??

Comment: and what? have you checked if UUID is serializable? (implements Serializable)

Comment: how can i implement serializable can you give me example or some link.. please....

Comment: In logcat this shows me java.lang.RuntimeException cannot serialize //here UUID

Comment: search for yourself. java Serialisation

Comment: alexwien thanks for what you help ....

Comment: Err, guys and @AlexWien this is SOAP, i.e. XML, not Serialization. Serialization does nt throw the exception described.

Comment: @omeriqbal Then search for java SOAP Serializatioon

Comment: i need example link i donot know what kind of help here..

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: yes i have done my self just use as string on android side